# How to create Kafka Topics in a Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I set up Kafka in Kubernetes and am now trying to set up some topics.
In the Kafka Apache Quick Start Guide are instructions on how to setup topics from the command line. So for me, the question arises: How do you setup topics in a Kubernetes setup? Because when a Kafka Cluster is redeployed, it is back to it's unconfigured state without any topics, correct? How do I make sure that after a deployment in Kubernetes, the needed topics are available?

I followed the Apache Kafka Quick Start Guide and the 'Guide to Setting Up Apache Kafka Using Docker' on Bealdung. I also did some further Google Research and read a few other guides, but none of them adressed this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with various Kafka operators, like the [Strimzi TopicOperator](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/main/examples/topic/kafka-topic.yaml), along with custom resource definitions (CRDs). Just be aware that if you're ever going to buy Confluent's enterprise services for kafka, they use an enterprise operator that is different from the open source versions. [Here's an article](https://medium.com/@btracebaader/kafka-topic-operator-how-to-manage-kafka-topics-in-kubernetes-d0290c8341dd) (couple of years old now) on medium that may help.

Alternatively, by default topics will be created automatically when your app tries to connect to them. Personally, I disable that behaviour because it makes it harder to notice mistakes, but it can help get started quite quickly.

Comment: Strimzi's TopicOperator works with any cluster. Confluent license is not required here. It's also recommended to disable auto topic creation

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of automatic topic creation either. It often leads to errors. I should have mentioned Strimzi specifically, I'll change the answer.

Comment: I'll also note the linked blog is not using Confluent Operator. They made their own operator for managing topics on Confluent Cloud

Answer (score -1):

While you can use Kubernetes operators to deploy topics, you can also use AdminClient API from your client code to ensure a topic exist before you connect a Producer/Consumer. This way, your client code is packaged alongside its dependencies, and will work with any Kafka cluster, rather than rely on the Kubernetes API to be available and a Topic Operator to be deployed.

You can also use Terraform, Ansible, or other solutions (e.g JulieOps) outside of the built-in CLI tools to create Kafka topics.

Comment: This is true, but, in practice, you tend to end up with a config map with the name of the topics you want to be created via the AdminClient API. And, to speed up development, you'll probably make that run every time the CM changes. At this point, you've already gone most of the way towards creating your own operator.

Comment: I was not recommending a CM. For example, in Spring Kafka, you use a `NewTopic` bean

Comment: Yeah, bu the OP asked about a Kubernetes setup, not java spring, terraform, or ansible.

Comment: And you can run each of the above using Pods (Spring-Kafka/Julie Ops), Argo Workflow or Airflow (Terraform/Ansible), etc. OP did not ask for Kubernetes **operators**